# how reliable is session in PHP

Tags: php, security, session

I am working on an ajax application just wondering how much reliable sessions are in terms of security.

Can I rely on session as User Identification and let them change they are password without asking for current password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just dont save sensitive data in sessions. They are also not very reliable in terms of "existence" ;)
2. Dont let anybody change a password without providing the current one. Imagine you just leave your computer and somebody change the password "for you".

Comment: OK, now why shouldn't i save sensitive data in session ?

Comment: Sessions are usually saved in text files, so the process, that creates the sessions, can read all files. You must take care yourself, that there is no way, that a script, which runs in the context of your webserver, may access any other session file than that of the current session. This is in most cases not that hard, but you dont need to think about it, if you dont put any sensitive data there ;)

Comment: I don't agree with point 1 (don't save sensitive data in sessions). Just treat session as any other unsafe storage (like a database). If you wouldn't store cleartext passwords (for example) in a DB, you'll want to do the same with the session. A session is just anyther type of storage (which has a special lifecycle)

Comment: As I mentioned Sessions are usually stored in files and files are much more vulnerable than databases. But independent from that: You must take care of the session files _and_ a database, if you use sessions as "temporary store".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by **how much reliable sessions are in term of security**.

But, regarding your other question, I would never allow a user to change his/her password without providing current one. The reason is simple: if I sit down on a computer with an authenticated session, I will be able to change *password* without actually owning that account.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are stored server-side, so they are as secure as possible.  That said, there is still the chance that someone will steal the unique session key for your site which then would give them full access to the user's account, but that is just the issue with storing stuff client-side.

You could do the second thing, but you could always do that even without a session ... so I'm not sure where you are going with that.  Putting in the current password is just for additional security measures / verification.

Answer (score 0):

Session uses a cookie. That cookie is vulnerable to all cookie-based attacks. Including firesheep style attacks.

You can change how PHP does cookies to only send them over SSL (Https). That helps, but doesn't prevent an attack that has access to that same machine from gaining access.

It is always a good idea to re-authenticate on password replacement. Just like you should never show a user their whole credit-card number, or SSN.

Answer (score 0):

Passwords shoud be always encoded so I not see why you have to store it in session password is reqired only one time when you logging to the page and then save some info in session saying user is signed maybe userid..